# Каково происхождение казачьих званий: "есаул", "атаман"?

Tags: этимология

С армейскими "лейтенант", "майор" и т.д. все понятно. А вот каково происхождение казачьих званий: *есаул, атаман*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Атаман"** есть у многих степных народов, где оно имело аналогичное значение, старший в роду, в клане. Откуда оно взялось там, не совсем понятно. Но вернее всего всё-таки из тюркских (Ата - отец). Версия родства с германскими крайне сомнительна, хотя и базируется на сходстве с польским и украинским "гетьман", восходящими к hauptmann.
**Есаул** - из турецкого: распорядитель, поверенный.
**Хорунжий** - из польского, восходит к "[тот, кто несет] хоругвь".
**Вахмистр** - от вахта, чин был и в других, неказачьих войсках.
Остальные чины в особых разъяснениях не нуждаются.